# Is there a name for the phenomenon of lines with only parentheses and other tokens that don't contain meaningful information for the programmer?

Tags: plugins, syntax, formatting, programming-languages, text-editor

so, maybe the most well-known thing in programming where what I'm talking about occurs frequently is callback hell in javascript.
Here's an example:

```js
fs.readdir(source, function (err, files) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error finding files: ' + err)
  } else {
    files.forEach(function (filename, fileIndex) {
      console.log(filename)
      gm(source + filename).size(function (err, values) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error identifying file size: ' + err)
        } else {
          console.log(filename + ' : ' + values)
          aspect = (values.width / values.height)
          widths.forEach(function (width, widthIndex) {
            height = Math.round(width / aspect)
            console.log('resizing ' + filename + 'to ' + height + 'x' + height)
            this.resize(width, height).write(dest + 'w' + width + '_' + filename, function(err) {
              if (err) console.log('Error writing file: ' + err)
            })
          }.bind(this))
        }
      })
    })
  }
})
```

This is taken from callbackhell.com ...
What I'm talking about occurs in the last  five lines: there are only braces and parens there and personally when I read the code those lines are essentially wasted space- they don't help me understand what's going on in this code since the extent of different code blocks is already shown via the indentation.

This kind of thing is at the moment really bugging me when programming in flutter, since there I naturally have deeply nested code when constructing widget trees.

The reason I'm asking is- I was wondering if there are techniques to avoid this kind of thing, both in terms of code styling, in general and/or for specific languages/frameworks, and in terms of tools. In my case the dart formatter by default formats the code to put parens on their own lines like this and I'm not sure I really want to look into configuring it to do something that strongly differs from common practices in that ecosystem, but I thought maybe there could be editor plugins for example that hide those lines by default. If there were a name for this searching for that kind of stuff would be a lot easier I'd wager.

Comment: If you write your code cleanly, you won't need to install a plugin to artificially make it look better. The problem here isn't just extra braces, it's the deep nesting that is hard to reason about due to high cyclomatic complexity. In languages without braces like Python, this would still be awful code. Use futures or promises, among other techniques.

Comment: sure, if I can avoid nesting I won't have this problem. But I think it's not always that simple- have a look at this:
https://dartpad.dev/40308e0a5f47acba46ba62f4d8be2bf4
This is one of the official dartpad samples demonstrating some flutter features... and it contains once 6 and once 8 consecutive lines with parens/braces.
Particularly in this case collapsing them into one line might be helpful, just because they take up quite a lot of space.

Comment: I disagree--hiding the braces makes it harder to parse the structure visually and just hides important information. This example is very different than your code above. In `runApp`, they could break the param out to another line, but `MaterialApp`'s nesting reflects the logical nesting of the components, like HTML. Same is true of `AnimatedAlign`--it makes sense to nest because that's the structure itself--it's nonlinear, while your pyramid of doom code isn't logically nested, it's logically chained, so the nesting is just a poor way of encoding chaining logic and should be fixed, not hidden.

Comment: Also, in this documentation example, if the nesting were to get any deeper, that'd likely be time to add abstraction and break out sub-components to prune the tree down (although I don't know anything about Dart). By hiding the braces, you would lose that visual signal that "something isn't right here and I need to abstract". It's much better to Do The Right Thing (tm) than try to bury the problem using an IDE plugin.

Comment: I still think that the 8 lines take away too much vertical space in my editor.
I guess the only thing I can reasonably do is throw my hands up and go like- if only dart used a lisp or python or similar where deep nesting which this HTML-like UI definition begets wouldn't clutter the file with multiple lines of mostly nothing that has to be there for syntactic purposes

Comment: Yeah, maybe languages with braces aren't for you. Lisp has even more of them (parentheses), but the typical style is to smush them all onto the last line. You could do the same here but people reading your code are going to find that surprising. My experience is that learning languages is less about imposing your preferences on it and more about learning to embrace its normal idioms. At the end of the day, follow the style the docs suggest, write the app and move on with life.